# "Error Cannot find module '/var/task/index" AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I'm currently coding a Node.js Alexa skill via Powershell, and I have been trying to code a function that you can use the echo dot as nightlight. I cloned the skill via github.
The code is:

```
import { SkillBuilders } from "ask-sdk-core";
import { AmazonCancelAndStopIntentHandler } from "./handlers/AMAZON_CancelAndStopIntentHandler";
import { AmazonHelpIntentHandler } from "./handlers/AMAZON_HelpIntentHandler";
import { CustomErrorHandler } from "./handlers/CustomErrorHandler";
import { GameEngineInputHandler } from "./handlers/GameEngine_InputHandler";
import { LaunchRequestHandler } from "./handlers/LaunchRequestHandler";
import { SessionEndedHandler } from "./handlers/SessionEndedHandler";
import { TimeIntentHandler } from "./handlers/TimeIntentHandler";
import { LogInterceptor } from "./interceptors/LogInterceptor";

export const handler = SkillBuilders.custom()
    .addRequestHandlers(
        new AmazonCancelAndStopIntentHandler(),
        new AmazonHelpIntentHandler(),
        new LaunchRequestHandler(),
        new SessionEndedHandler(),
        new TimeIntentHandler(),
        new GameEngineInputHandler(),
    )
    .addErrorHandlers(
        new CustomErrorHandler(),
    )
    .addRequestInterceptors(
        new LogInterceptor(),
    )
    .addResponseInterceptors(
        new LogInterceptor(),
    )
    .lambda();`
```

When I upload it via `ask deploy` or zip it and upload it via aws lambda, I get this error

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find module '/var/task/index'",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)",

    "Module.require (module.js:596:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:11:18)"
  ]
}
```

This is the Outpot log

```
START RequestId: 68837f04-333e-453f-b643-1818f2a33807 Version: $LATEST
Unable to import module 'index': Error
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
END RequestId: 68837f04-333e-453f-b643-1818f2a33807
REPORT RequestId: 68837f04-333e-453f-b643-1818f2a33807  Duration: 53.20 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 58 MB  Init Duration: 0.98 ms
```

I tried to zip only the files, give the permission to node_modules folder, I checked the index.hadler and I installed module-js, request modules, and many other Node modules.

This is my directory

```
│   index.ts
│   package-lock.json
│   package.json
│   
├───handlers
│       AMAZON_CancelAndStopIntentHandler.ts
│       AMAZON_HelpIntentHandler.ts
│       CustomErrorHandler.ts
│       GameEngine_InputHandler.ts
│       LaunchRequestHandler.ts
│       SessionEndedHandler.ts
│       TimeIntentHandler.ts
│       
├───interceptors
│       LogInterceptor.ts
│       
├───node_modules
│        
└───utils
        ColorCycle.ts
        Constants.ts
        Directives.ts
        SilenceGenerator.ts
```

Comment: Are you deploying Typescript code directly to Lambda, or transpiling it to Javascript first? (Lambda/Node doesn't support direct execution of Typescript code).

Comment: @MarcoLüthy I think the first one. Sorry, I am a newbie.
I tried to deploy it via Powershell and also upload it via Aws

Comment: I tried to edit the code but I still get the error.

Comment: I still can't solve this problem. Someone can help?